# How to transfer data from one datatable to another datatable

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2015, datatable

I'm trying to transfer the data where when i click on the skip button, the data will move into another table. I am unsure on how to code it to transfer from the queue table to missedQueue table. Please help :(

This is my code:

```
protected void BtnSkip_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ActivityTimer.Enabled = false;
        BtnSkip.Enabled = true;
        string timeCurrent = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss");
        string sql13 = "UPDATE queue SET status_id = 6, serve_status = 'Missed', queue_time = '{0}'" //Update Status ID, Serve Status, Queue Time
                              + " WHERE number = '{1}'";
        string sql = "SELECT name, p.nric, number, prescription_id FROM patient p, queue q" + " WHERE p.nric = q.nric AND status_id = 7 ORDER BY q.queue_time";
        DataSet dsR = DBMgr.GetDataSet(sql);
        try
        {
            sql13 = String.Format(sql13, timeCurrent, int.Parse(dsR.Tables[0].Rows[0]["number"].ToString()));
            if (DBMgr.ExecuteSQL(sql13) == 1)
            {
                LtlMsg.Text = "Missed!";
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Currently you are updating the table queue. What data do you want to transfer to the table missedQueue? Is the update still necessary?

Comment: I need to transfer the one whole row of the data like ** queue_id, nric, prescription_id, queueno_id, number, status_id, queue_date, queue_time, serve_status **. And i just need to update the serve status and status id.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to transfer row than you should execute query like

```
INSERT INTO missedQueue(...) SELECT (...) from queue where number '{0}'
```

Than you should delete row from queue (update if you need it)

Comment: the missedQueue(...) is the code in the bracket the 'VALUES(..)'?